# AMP and Google Analytics 4 Issue

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, amp-html

As of now, we can not make a google universal analytics property, I would trying to find a way to add GA4 script or measurement id in WordPress AMP Plugin by AMP Project Contributors. Can anybody tell me a way to do it? How to add FB Pixel in AMP will be Bonus.

Comment: GA4 is not supported with AMP yet, why you can not make UA property again?
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/24621#issuecomment-793035755

Comment: If you make a new GA property it doesn't give any choices between GA4 or UA. It's GA4 by default. Correct me if there is any way to do that.

Comment: I understand it may confusing a bit as by default they ask you to create GA4 property 
you can click on more "show advance options" and the UA property will show up check the screenshot
https://prnt.sc/1128mee